# Extracting the @Field parameter from retrofit with Node.js Express

Tags: java, android, node.js, express, retrofit

I am trying to make an app in Android and have some problem. I have searched the web but I haven't found an obvious solution.

In my Android app I send a Post request for a login task using Retrofit.

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/login")
Call<Boolean> loginUser(@Field("username") String userName, @Field("password") String password);
```

My server is in Node.js with express and I don't know how to extract the username and password parameters.

my app.js file looks like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');

var connection = require('./dbConnection');

var app = express();
require('./models')(app);
require('./controllers')(app);
require('./routes')(app);

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());

connection.init();

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

And my routes file for login looks like this:

```
var loginM = require('../models/login');
var loginC = require('../controllers/login');

module.exports = function(app) {

    app.post('/login/', function(req, res, next) {
        loginM.attemptLogin(req.body, res);
    });
}
```

req.body does not seem to give me the @Field variables, I have tried req.headers and req.params as well with no success. Can someone explain how to extract them?

Much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On NodeJs side, or better: `expressjs` app side, you need to use a `body-parser` middleware, such as https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

`npm install body-parser --save`

Since `body-parser` supports [JSON](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions) as well as [URL encoded](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions) input (which retrofit [@Field](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Field.html) generates) you need to add appropriate middleware functions to app:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// parse JSON inputs
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Also, parse URL encoded inputs
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

// handle requests
app.post('/login/', function(req, res, next) {
   loginM.attemptLogin(req.body, res);
});
```

**Also**, remember that you add `body-parser` middleware **Before** adding routes/controllers to the app. Because parser middleware should be executed before so that input is parsed by the time request handling logic is executed.

```
var app = express();

// first
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());

// after
require('./models')(app);
require('./controllers')(app);
require('./routes')(app);
```

Comment: I have the body-parser installed and included in the app.js file. Do I need to include it in the routes file as well where my second snippet is placed?

Comment: @Aidin Do you have `bodyParser.urlencoded()` being used by the `app` before the route is defined ?

Comment: @Aidin See last part of updated answer. You need to move the `app.use(bodyparser...` lines before applying routes / controllers etc.

Comment: Oh, ok! Unfortunately I am not able to test it now as I am at work. I will hopefully be able to do it tonight. If it works I mark your answer as accepted. Thank you

Comment: I just had the chance to try it out and it worked spendidly :) And I could confirm @ Field variables transer in the body. Thanks